# Blackjack Javascript: Remove item in an object or an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have completed a Blackjack tutorial, with some issues left unsolved in it (for tutorial purposes maybe).

I am attempting to remove a card object from a collection once that card has been dealt.

Here is the data/object code I have been using throughout the tutorial:

```
let blackjackGame = {
    'you': {"scoreSpan": '#your-blackjack-result', 'div': '#your-box', 'score': 0},
    'dealer': {"scoreSpan": '#dealer-blackjack-result', 'div': '#dealer-box', 'score': 0},
    'cards': ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'K', 'J', 'Q', 'A'],
    'cardsMap': {'2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, '10': 10, 'K': 10, 'J': 10, 'Q': 10, 'A': [1, 11]}, };
```

I have tried using the **delete()** method for the **blackjackGame** objects' *cards* array and the *cardsMap* object on my deal() functions here:

```
function blackjackDeal() {
    if (blackjackGame['turnsOver'] === true) {
        blackjackGame['isStand'] = false;
        let yourImages = document.querySelector('#your-box').querySelectorAll('img');
        let dealerImages = document.querySelector('#dealer-box').querySelectorAll('img');
        for (i=0; i < yourImages.length; i++) {
            yourImages[i].remove();
        }
        for (i=0; i < dealerImages.length; i++) {
            dealerImages[i].remove();
        }
        YOU['score'] = 0;
        DEALER['score'] = 0;
        document.querySelector('#your-blackjack-result').textContent = 0;
        document.querySelector('#dealer-blackjack-result').textContent = 0;
        document.querySelector('#your-blackjack-result').style.color = 'white';
        document.querySelector('#dealer-blackjack-result').style.color = 'white';
        document.querySelector('#blackjack-result').textContent = "Let's play!";
        document.querySelector('#blackjack-result').style.color = 'black';
        blackjackGame['turnsOver'] = true;
    }
 }
```

And the **dealerLogic()** function:

```
async function dealerLogic() {
    blackjackGame['isStand'] = true;
    while(DEALER['score'] < 16 && blackjackGame['isStand'] === true) {
        let card = randomCard();
        let copy = card;
        showCard(copy, DEALER);
        updateScore(copy, DEALER);
        showScore(DEALER);
        await sleep(1000);
    }
    blackjackGame['turnsOver'] = true;
    let winner = computeWinner();
    showResult(winner);
}
```

You will notice I have tried to make *copies* of the **blackjackGame** object and array, but the cards don't go anywhere.

All the code logic in these two functions and the **blackjackGame** variable works fine, this part wasn't covered in the tutorial (which is fine), I'm just very interested in how to do this, as I did years ago with a lottery prediction machine in JavaScript (a long time ago).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you making copies of `blackjackGame`? Where do you use `delete`?

Comment: I think that you need some `deck` array with all the cards if you want to remove anything. you should put your remove logic when you call `randomCard`

Comment: I was making copies just below the randomcard() functions are called, I was using the delete() methods at the bottom of each function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you concider adding a property to the cards that specifies if the card had been delt or not ? for example

```js
let blackjackGame = {
    'you': {"scoreSpan": '#your-blackjack-result', 'div': '#your-box', 'score': 0},
    'dealer': {"scoreSpan": '#dealer-blackjack-result', 'div': '#dealer-box', 'score': 0},
    'cards': [
      {"card": 2, "isDealt": false},
      {"card": 3, "isDealt": false},
      {"card": 4, "isDealt": false},
      // the other cards ....
      {"card": 'A', "isDealt": false}
      ],
    'cardsMap': {'2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, '10': 10, 'K': 10, 'J': 10, 'Q': 10, 'A': [1, 11]}, };
```

And whenever a card is dealt, you change the property `isDealt` to `true`. And only serve cards that fulfill the condition `blackjackGame.cards[i].isDealt === false`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The answer helped me in the right direction.

```
let blackjackGame = {
    'hearts': {"card2": 2, "isDealt": false, "card3": 3, "isDealt": false, "card4": 4, "isDealt": false,
               "card5": 5, "isDealt": false, "card6": 6, "isDealt": false, "card7": 7, "isDealt": false,
               "card8": 8, "isDealt": false, "card9": 9, "isDealt": false, "card10": 10, "isDealt": false,
               "cardK": 10, "isDealt": false, "cardJ": 10, "isDealt": false, "cardQ": 10, "isDealt": false,
               "cardA": [1, 11]},
    
};
console.log(delete(blackjackGame['hearts']['card2']));
```

It outputs to *true* on the console, thus deleting the property of the JavaScript object.